# Spring Boot MVC application breaks after some time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, deployment, web-hosting, spring-thymeleaf

I have a spring boot mvc + thymeleaf application and pretty much completed. so I also brought a VPS server from hostinger. When I deploy my spring boot app everything is OK, it works properly but after some moment my application is breaks. Why is it happening? Where is the my mistake? here is the following screen image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYFBG.png)

Comment: Enable Apache HTTP logging and check if the request reaching your server or not.

Comment: I figured it out my issue. the issue is memory failure (RAM). so I upgraded my vps plan to at least 4 GB and the problem is solved